# Accessing Dynamic Objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an API response code below. When the API returns a validation error, it contains either a string or an array within an object. The key of the object represents the field from the front-end:

```json
{
    errors: {
        name: ['The field is required'],
        email: ['The field should be an email'],
    }
}
```

In the front end, I use react and typescript and write interfaces like this

```js
export interface ApiError {
  [name: string | number]: string | string[]
}
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
  code?: number,
  status?: string,
  message?: string,
  data?: null | Array<T> | T,
  errors?: ApiError | string,
}
```

I have difficulty to access the error message in the component

```js
<div>
   <input type="name" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
   <InputMessage errors={response?.errors?.email! || ''} /> // TS2339: Property  email  does not exist on type  string | ApiError
</div>
```

Of course, here's another variation:

How can I access a dynamic object key? Should I pass a generic type for validation? I'm seeking a simple solution similar to plain JavaScript, allowing for one-line access with a null fallback when the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Either add a check that it's an object and not a string, or a type assertion (`… as ApiError`), or add another type parameter to your generic `ApiResponse` to be able to specify which `errors` type you expect

Comment: Error messages can be stored in a state variable when the result is received through the API. It  is easily or dynamically handle.

Comment: I can do `const errors = submitResult?.response?.errors as ApiError;` and access with `<Input errors={errors?.name} />`, is there other approach?

Answer (score 0):

To access a dynamic object key in TypeScript, you can use the `keyof` keyword combined with an indexed access operator. Here's how you can modify your code to access the error messages in a simple and type-safe way:

First, update your `ApiResponse` interface to use a generic type for errors:

```js
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
  code?: number;
  status?: string;
  message?: string;
  data?: null | Array<T> | T;
  errors?: ApiError;
}
```

Now, in your component, you can access error messages for a specific field using a generic type parameter:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps {
  response: ApiResponse<any>; // Replace 'any' with the appropriate data type for your response.
  fieldName: keyof ApiError;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ response, fieldName }) => {
  const errors = response.errors;
  let error: string | string[] = '';

  if (errors) {
    error = typeof errors[fieldName] === 'string' ? errors[fieldName] : errors[fieldName]?.[0] || '';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="name" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <InputMessage errors={error} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, you can use the `MyComponent` by passing the `fieldName` and the `response` object:

```js
<MyComponent response={response} fieldName="email" />
```

This approach allows you to access error messages dynamically while ensuring type safety in your React component.

Comment: I already implement that, the component has props the object of error and the key, but I want to passing the array or string of the array directly `response?.errors?.email` without separating the key of object

Comment: In this updated code, checked the type of errors[fieldName]. If it's a string, we assign it directly to the error variable. If it's an array, we take the first element of the array (if it exists) or assign an empty string as a fallback. This way, you can use MyComponent with response?.errors?.email without separating the key of the object.